# How to use varnish to wait for backend brief deployment delay?

Tags: continuous-integration, varnish

Here is the situation, Jenkins auto deploys the war to qat glassfish server

During deployment, usually several seconds, how can I instruct varnish to put *all* in coming requests on hold?

Currently the client will see 404 for a short while

Answer (score 0):

You can set a temporary vcl in your CI system.

```
vcl.load deploy-config /etc/varnish/deploy.vcl
vcl.use deploy-config
```

And at finishing the deployment do the same for your ordinary config. This is how you usually do it for scheduled maintenance or temporary (load) problems.

I dont know how your server application solution works but it would be strange if there is no way to make an instant switch of the application used live.

Comment: this is for our qat, which has only 1 application server ... in order to implement the auto switch, I need to setup another *standby* app server, which is a bit over kill for my current case